# CruiseControl.NET and Git

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

It looks like there is no built-in support for [Git](http://git-scm.com/) in [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET).

Anyone have suggestions on Git plug-ins, tips, or other advice on getting CruiseControl.NET with work with Git?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a CC.net/git plugin at github:

[ccnet.git.plugin](http://github.com/dogeth/ccnet.git.plugin/tree/master)

The rdoc includes instructions for configuring CC.net to use a git repository.

Answer (score 21):

I just wanted to note that newer CruiseControl.net have builtin support for git

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git

Answer (score 6):

Integration of git/mercurial support for 1.5 release of CruiseControl.Net is currently worked on - the git plugin AFAIK has already been integrated into main repository.

[Mercurial is already included in documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Mercurial+Source+Control+Block).

Comment: Yes, I just checked and 1.5 does indeed have both git and mercurial native

Answer (score 4):

The Git support was added in CC.NET 1.5 according to the documentation.

Since Thoughtworks seems to be having issues with their public CruiseControl.NET site I wanted to mention that full coverage about the "official" Git Source Control block can be found in the documentation that ships with the CruiseControl.NET installation:

- Locally on a default 64-bit Windows install: `file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/CruiseControl.NET/webdashboard/doc/CCNET/Git%20Source%20Control%20Block.html`
- On your remote build server: http://buildserver/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Git%20Source%20Control%20Block.html

It seems like the official plugin has some added features about tagging and checking in files modified during the build.