# How to get source code from msysgit so cruise control.net can build

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I'm currently setting up a development environment at home to learn technologies I won't have a change to use at work. I have setup msysgit on my local machine and I have a Virtual PC with cruise Control.Net installed. I'm the only developer on this project and I don't want to use a hosted git repository, as I'm doing this for a friend and he doesn't want the source code public.

Given that git doesn't have a central repository I'm not sure how to structure everything. How can I get the source code from git to cruise control so it can build? Should I use git demon, SSH or should I have the source on the cruise control machine and push from my development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your setup I'm not sure it's worth setting up git-daemon or ssh.

I would simply have a repository on my development machine where I do all the work and keep a clone of it on the build machine using network shares. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945887/cruisecontrol-net-and-git) on how to interact with git from CC.

Comment: Thanks for the info Idan. I will use a network share and create a bare repository on the CI server to push too.